# ReCaptcha nofunciana correctamente

Tags: php, formularios, google-forms, recaptcha

Como estan? tengo una duda hacer del recaptcha de google. La integracion del mismo cre que la eh hecho correctamente. Pero a la hora de que el usuario quiere avanzar en el envio del formulario y el captcha no esta marcado, se envía igual. Mi idea es que si el captcha no está marcado y el usuario presiona el botón enviar no pueda enviarlo y le salga una validación que diga que debe validar el captcha.

```
 $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
      $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
      $secretKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
      $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secretKey}&response={$captcha}&remoteip={$ip}");
      $atributos = json_decode($response, FALSE);

      if (!$atributos['success']) {
        alert("verificar captcha");
      }
    }
```

Este es el codigo php y abajo dejo como esta hecho mi formulario en html:

```
<form action="/partials/form.php" method="POST" id="formularioContacto">
    <p>Nombre y Apellido*</p>
    <input name="nombre" type="text"  id="" required>
    <p>Correo, Email:*</p>
    <input  name="email" type="email" id="" required>
    <p>Consulta:*</p>
    <textarea name="consulta" id="" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
    <p>* son campos obligatorios</p>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnEnviar">
```